# Pytest - Fixture introspect on function level

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, introspection

I've got a fixture that requires a variable from the test function. Using introspection and declaring the variable in the function namespace/context should work if introspection on function level works, as it does for module level, but each time I run the code I end up with None instead of the string "Fancy Table".

In the fixture I set the scope to 'function' and then introspect via getattr and request.function:

```
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def table(request):
    from data_setup import create_table
    table_name = getattr(request.function, "table_name", None)
    create_table(request, table_name)
```

I declare the variable table_name in the test function:

```
#test_file.py
class TestTable():

    @pytest.mark.tags("table")
    def test_create_table(self, test_db):
        table_name = "Fancy Table"
        current_page = TablePage(self.test_driver, test_db)
        current_page.go_to_kitchen("Eva", "Evas Kitchen")
        current_page.create_first_table(expected_table_name)
        Validation.assert_equal(expected_table_name, current_page.get_name(), "Table had the wrong name!")
```

Doing this on a module level has worked, as has class but as soon as I attempt to do so on a function level the fixture spits out None again. Am I using fixture introspection on a function level wrong? How is it used if not like this?

Answer (score 2):

Function variables are local and are destroyed after the function returns, they are not bound the function object in any way... this is how Python works and not related to `py.test`.

Your example will work if you bind the `table_name` local variable explicitly to the test function, effectively letting it outlive its usual life-time:

```
@pytest.mark.tags("table")
def test_create_table(self, test_db):
    test_create_table.table_name = "Fancy Table"
```

On the other hand, wouldn't be simpler to just pass the `table_name` to `TablePage` explicitly? It would be simpler, straightforward and, well, explicit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly binding the local variable to the test function resulted in my IDE complaining about an Unresolved reference. What else do we need to know to make this work?

In the example given, when I write `test_create_table.table_name = "Fancy Table"`, the `test_create_table` part is the part my IDE complains has an Unresolved reference. So given I am receiving the Unresolved reference error, how can I successfully explicitly bind the local variable?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason solution provided by Bruno didn't work for me. this is what i did

```
import inspect

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def custom_fixture(request):
    sig = inspect.signature(request.function)

    my_fixture_obj = None

    if 'fixture_data' in sig.parameters:
        fixture_data = sig.parameters['fixture_data'].default

        my_fixture_obj = MyFixtureObject(fixture_data['data'])

    yield my_fixture_obj

    # cleanup my_fixture_obj


def test_sample1(custom_fixture, fixture_data = {'data': ['s1', 's2', 's3']}):
    ...

def test_sample2(custom_fixture, fixture_data = {'data': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']}):
    ...
```